# Mount Volume on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mount

I have a local volume with a number of files I require for provisioning my EC2 instance.  I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for how I am should go about mounting this volume on my EC2/transferring these files so they are accessible by my instance.  What is the best method to do this in terms of speed + security?

Comment: How many files ?  How many GB of data?

Comment: I don't need two way access -- i just need to dump a bunch of data from my local volume to my ec2 at every launch

Answer (score 1):

couple of options:

- upload it to s3 and pull it down from s3 when provisioning (you are going to need the extra space)
- create an instance, attach and EBS volume and transfer the files to that volume and snapshot. When provisioning create a new volume from the snapshot and attach it.
- use something like s3fs (fuse-based) to mount the volume (similar with 1st option with less space but more complicated.
- build an AMI with things already provisioned/configured. (downside: way more complex than the others)

As far as speed go if you use the same region for the instance as for S3/EBS you should be fine.

As far as security goes that controlled at IAM level for the resources you chose to use. Key here is speed at spinning up / tearing down new instances.

If it was me the AMI route is probably the one I would take

Answer (score 0):

If the data doesn't change much and you just have a 30gb data load for your server on startup then I would put it in an ebs volume, snapshot it, then create a volumen from the snapshot on boot up.  The other advantage of this is if you have two or more instances that will use the same 30GB of data over and over.  They just grab the same snapshot, create their own volume for it and attach.  No data transfer charges here since they are attaching a volume not copying the data.

Or you could just zip (tar.gz) the whole bundle and put it into S3.  Have your instance boot up and grab the file from S3 and then extract onto their own local disk.  The neat part of this way is you have the server grab the same filename every time.  You could upload a new version of your files, make sure it is named the same thing and then your next server would grab the new file.  You will get charged for data transfer in this scenario but at inside AWS rates which are super cheap.